# Failing to set table heading if there are merged rows

Tags: vba, ms-word, heading

I want to set all tables in ms-Word file with a repeating heading displayed on every page.

but finnaly I found that if a table (who has an index as idx in the following code) has merged rows, then 
`ActiveDocument.Tables(idx).Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True` 
fails and says

> method "item" of object "rows" failed

any hints? thanks

Comment: Did my answer help you? If yes, please take a moment to mark it as the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it. This is helpful for the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this by selecting the cells (rows) to be repeated - that's how/why it works in the user interface. The tricky part is, of course, knowing the "shape" of the table in order to correctly make the selection.

If you can't know this going in, perhaps the best approach would be to use error handling so that the macro can "prompt" you to give the number of cells that make up the repeating rows. Here's one way to go about it.

(Note: it's not possible to pause a macro's execution other than by showing a message of some kind. If you want to wait until the user can actually make the selection in the table, then the macro would need to be restarted.)

```
Sub SetHeaderRepeatWithMergedRows()
    Dim tbl As word.Table
    Dim errNr As Long
    Dim nrCells As Variant
    Dim startCell As word.Range
    Dim endCell As word.Range

    'Cannot access individual rows in this collection because
    'table has vertically merged cells
    errNr = 5991 'or? method "item" of object "rows" failed
    nrCells = "none"
    On Error GoTo handler
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        tbl.Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True
    Next

    Exit Sub

handler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case errNr
            'Rows with vertically merged cells can only be set
            'as Header Rows on the Selection, so select the
            'necessary number of cells by prompting the user
            Do
                'Make sure the table is visible to the user:
                tbl.Range.Document.ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView tbl.Range, True
                nrCells = InputBox("How many cells make up the table header:")
                If IsNumeric(nrCells) Then
                    tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Select
                    Selection.MoveEnd wdCell, nrCells - 1
                    Selection.Rows.HeadingFormat = True
                End If
            Loop Until IsNumeric(nrCells)
            nrCells = "none"
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            MsgBox Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description & _
              vbCr & "The macro will end, now"
    End Select
End Sub
```