# Select two rows with merged Cells to mark as Header

Tags: vba, ms-word, rows, selection

I have a macro that takes data from different worksheets of my workbook and writes it into a word file. It does what it should the only problem occurs when I try to mark some cells as the header of the table. I want to have the two top rows as a header of my table but the two rows contain some merged cells, the layout of the merged cells can be seen in the attached image.
[image: layout of merged cells]
and because of that I receive the runtime error 5991 complaining about merged cells.

If I select the rows in questions manually in word and do the right click -> properties -> header check it works as intended so I suspect that the problem lies in the selection of the rows. It seems like a very simple fix but I am just unable to figure out the correct keywords for finding the right answer.

```vb
Sub mytry()
    Dim tblRange As Excel.Range
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim WordTable As Word.Table
    Dim str As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Integer, lCol As Integer
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
    If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")
    
    WordApp.Visible = True
    WordApp.Activate

    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(Template:="filename", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)
    
    For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Produces a String of Placeholders for the Word template as I don't know in advance how many worksheets there are
        str = str & "<<" & Ws.Name & "_Heading>>" & vbLf & "<<" & Ws.Name & "_Content>>"
    Next
    
    With WordDoc
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<Data>>" ' Placeholder in the Word Template where all of my Data goes.
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = str
    End With
    
    For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' finds last used Cell in the Worksheet
        lRow = Ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
        lCol = Ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column
        str = SpaltNoZuBuchst(lCol) & CStr(lRow)
        Debug.Print str

        Set tblRange = Ws.Range("A1:" & str)
        tblRange.Copy

        With WordDoc
            .Application.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="<<" & Ws.Name & "_Heading>>", MatchCase:=True, MatchWholeWord:=True
            .Application.Selection = Ws.Name
            .Application.Selection.Style = WordDoc.Styles("Heading 1")
            .Application.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=" _ ", MatchCase:=True, MatchWholeWord:=True, ReplaceWith:=" / "
            .Application.Selection.Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
            .Application.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="<<" & Ws.Name & "_Content>>", MatchCase:=True, MatchWholeWord:=True
            .Application.Selection.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False
        End With
        i = i + 1 ' indexes the newly inserted Table
        Set WordTable = WordDoc.Tables(i)
        WordTable.Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True
        WordTable.Rows(2).HeadingFormat = True ' first and second row contain Heading Information
        WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
        WordDoc.Application.Selection.Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
        WordDoc.Application.Selection.InsertBreak
    Next

    WordDoc.TablesOfContents(1).Update
    WordDoc.Fields.Update
End Sub

Function SpaltNoZuBuchst(Num As Integer) As String
    Dim eins As Integer, zwei As Integer
    Dim str As String
    
    eins = Int((Num - 1) / 26)
    If eins - 1 > 0 Then zwei = Int((eins - 1) / 26)
    
    If zwei > 0 Then str = Chr(zwei + 64)
    If eins - zwei * 26 > 0 Then str = str + Chr(eins - zwei * 26 + 64)
    str = str + Chr(Num - eins * 26 + 64)
    
    SpaltNoZuBuchst = str
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

See here:

[Failing to set table heading if there are merged rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522150/failing-to-set-table-heading-if-there-are-merged-rows)

Adapted from the linked post:

```
WordTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Select
Selection.MoveEnd wdCell, 10   '<< how many cells in top 2 rows 
Selection.Rows.HeadingFormat = True
```

You can get the cell count from your Excel range...